# How to create containers based on enum

Tags: c++, stl, enums, containers

Well I'm designign publish/subsribe pattern (it's not observer pattern! many people confuse this). My problem is:

I have enum with topics:

```
  enum topics {gui, combat, physics};
```

Then for every topic I need 2 containers. Currently I do it maually:

```
  std::vector <cSubscriber *> guiSubscribers;
  std::vector <cEvent> guiEvents;
```

What I want to do is to have a container of vector which uses enum as key. I mean that I can access it in the following way:

```
events[gui] //it gives me access to vector of gui events
subscribers[combat] //this gives me access to vector of combat subscribers
```

The key in [] has to be a value from the enum. Is there any way of doing this or I need to do it manually for every topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is a `std::map<topics, std::vector<cEvent>>`.  However, this is potentially overkill, given that you only have 3 enum values, which will be numbered 0, 1, and 2...

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I want.

Comment: I will have more enum values, that was just an example.

Comment: Is it something wrong in my code or this map doesn't allow me to use integers as key?

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to use a vector, if the number of elements is known beforehand?
How about a solution like that:

```
template<class T> struct topics {
    T gui, combat, physics
};

topics<cSubscriber *> guiSubscribers;
topics<cEvent> guiEvents;
```